# Nintex webservice for publishing workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, web-services, publishing

I've installed Nintex Workflows 2013. But when I'm trying to publish a workflow through the Nintex Webservice, it fails.
What I've done:

1) Got my file as a string
2) Changed values in workflow
3) Convert to byte array
4) Connect to Nintex Workflow Service -> My problem...
5) Publish workflow to web

The code (for point nr 4):
I've added a service reference to the webservice (=NintexWorkflowWS)
But I need to set the URL and credentials (since this will be deployed on test/production)

```
private void ActivateWorkflow(byte[] doc, string teamRoomUrl)
{
    NintexWorkflowWS.NintexWorkflowWS webService = new NintexWorkflowWS.NintexWorkflowWS();
    webService.Url = teamRoomUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/_vti_bin/nintexworkflow/workflow.asmx";
    webService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    webService.PublishFromNWF(doc, "Documents", "Move Documents", true);
}
```

On the last line it throws an error:

```
{System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
  at ...
```

This always fails... Does anyone knows how to do this???

Comment: The Nintex forums are better suited for this type of question, which is why it attracted the close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer... just had to run this in elevated permissions:

```
private void ActivateWorkflow(byte[] doc, string teamRoomUrl)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        try
        {
            NintexWorkflowWS.NintexWorkflowWS webService = new NintexWorkflowWS.NintexWorkflowWS();
            webService.Url = teamRoomUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/_vti_bin/nintexworkflow/workflow.asmx";
            webService.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            webService.PublishFromNWF(doc, "Documents", "Move Documents", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log
        }
    });
}
```